# Can't generate cancan:ability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

In ruby on rails gemfile i added gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10', then ran bundle install and after that rails g cancan:ability.

This is what i get in my console

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 3455
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--jbuilder'; got true (boolean)
Expected boolean default value for '--markerb'; got :erb (string)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--helper'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--assets'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Could not find generator 'cancan:ability'. Maybe you meant 'channel', 'coffee:assets' or 'css:assets'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

Comment: just a hunch but could u somehow stop the spring process? spring stop in terminal should do

Comment: Thanks it worked! But i still get 'Running via Spring preloader in process 10707' and pair 'Expected string default value for..' It's nothing bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runned 'spring stop' command and problem solved.