# error when running rails g cancan:ability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I added the gem `cancancan`, `~> 1.10` to my gemfile and then ran bundle install.

That all went well but then I get the following in my terminal when I run `> rails g cancan:ability`:

> Running via Spring preloader in process 967 Could not find generator 'cancan:ability'. Maybe you meant 'coffee:assets', 'channel' or 'css:assets' Run rails generate --help for more options.

I tried running the command `spring stop` and then ran `rails g cancan:ability` and I get the same message.

Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think there are same issue in https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/issues/428 and in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683981/cant-generate-cancanability. Did you look in these links?

Comment: I did see the suggestion in Stackoverflow about running spring stop. And I did try that which did not work. It looks like I will have to follow the suggestion from github.com. I did not see that before. Thanks for posting that @kos